# Grindelwald rallies at the cemetery tonight, and there will be death

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Nicolas Flamel: Grindelwald rallies at the cemetery tonight, and there will be death.

I am trying to understand what "rally" means in this context.

It's a new word to me, so I looked it up in [the dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rally) and found out that it could mean either "to conduct a large meeting" or "to recover and become stronger".

Both options might fit into the plot, so the sentence is very ambiguous to me.

EDIT:

The thing I am trying to grasp is whether Nicolas Flamel knew the upcoming event would strengthen Grindelwald or he just reported that the meeting is about to take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be both at once. To *rally one's forces* meant to gather them together, perhaps to recover, reorganise, gather strength, etc. I believe this is the origin of the 'large meeting' sense.

Comment: Grindelwald organising a rally is a terrible message to hear. It requires no further discussion, but action. I get it. Thank you.